# Avoiding nesting if/else if as well as avoiding InvalidOperationException at the same time in a conditional statement

Tags: c#, anti-patterns

I encountered this huge method where I have lots of if else statements of the type

```
else if (ptName == "Missile" ||
         ptName == "Telephone" ||
        (ptName.StartsWith("Car") && gasTank.ValueFloat1.Value < 90))
        {
         foo_1 = "some_string";
        }
```

Unfortunately this code is not completely correct since the variable gasTank is only defined by cases where ptName starts with the string "Car". Thus, during runtime I get the

> InvalidOperationException occured: Null object must have a value.

This could be solved by nesting ifs and else ifs, as well as repeating the condition `ptName.StartsWith("Car")`, although it is highly undesirable.

Splitting the method into many little ones or adding return after each condition is not an option, since the method's return is a concatenation of various `foo_i`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: normally gasTank would not be tested unless StartsWith("Car") is true..  unless you have stuff in there starting with car and not having gasTanks

Comment: Boolean operators in C# are short-circuiting, the right operand should not be evaluated if the left one is enough to obtain a value. You could possibly fall into a scenario where `ptName` **starts with** `Car` but there's no `ValueFloat1` in `gasTank`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Condition

```
ptName.StartsWith("Car")
```

should become

```
ptName?.StartsWith("Car") ?? false
```

That would spare you from `null` value.

If you are using C# version below 6, then you should use:

```
ptNAme == null ? false : ptName.StartsWith("Car")
```

Another update:

```
(gasTank.ValueFloat1?.Value ?? 0) < 90
```

or

```
(gasTank.ValueFloat1.HasValue ? gasTank.ValueFloat1.Value : 0) < 90
```

Comment: Many thanks, I think I am getting closer with this, although I get the logic don't I need a *:* after using the *?* operator ?

Comment: @user94028 Well, you would be right if it was ternary operator, but here meaning of `?` is different, see this: [Safe Navigation Operator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/). If the answer helped you, you should accept it by checking green check mark on the left

Comment: The problem is that if I do this change I get a syntax error where it expects a *:* from your link, it looks like I am not using a C# version where this is allowed, since this is C# 3.0

Comment: @user94028 Updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error. 

ptName is a variable whose value is never null, it may just be something else than "Car", in any case the second condition gasTank.ValueFloat1.Value < 90 gets evaluated and gasTank == null whenever ptName != "Car".